# TypeError: string indices must be integers JSON with backslash

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, request

I'm try to scraping JSON data from script tags. And I was able to extract data from it.

My Code.

```python
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
head = {
    "Accept": 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,km;q=0.7",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Host": "www.ixigua.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
url = "https://www.ixigua.com/home/58484635562"
ree = requests.get(url, headers=head)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ree.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')[-2].text
print(script)

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(script, f, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Result below

```
"window._SSR_HYDRATED_DATA={\"recommendFeed\":null,\"attentionFeed\":null,\"nbaFeed\":null,\"livingFeed\":null,\"channelFeed\":[],\"homeFeed\":null,\"adBanner\":[],\"channelInfo\":null,\"ChannelFeedList\":[],\"UserDetail\":{\"enableTabs\":[],\"hotPersonList\":[],\"userInfo\":{\"name\":\"-\",\"description\":\"-\",\"avatar\":\"\",\"followersCount\":0,\"followingCount\":0,\"user_id\":\"\",\"follow\":false},\"videoData\":{\"videoList\":[],\"loading\":true},\"hotsoonData\":{\"hotsoonList\":[]},\"preview_series\":[],\"seriesData\":{\"series_list\":[],\"hasMore\":false,\"nextCursor\":\"0\"}},\"FooterLinks\":[],\"LvideoChannel\":[],\"LvideoChannelOnTcc\":[],\"LvideoCategory\":[],\"AlbumInCategory\":[],\"ChannelFeedV2\":[],\"ChannelLevelOneConfig\":[],\"ChannelLevelTwoConfig\":[],\"HighQualityFeed\":[],\"ChannelBannerConfig\":[],\"Teleplay\":null,\"Projection\":{\"video\":{},\"series\":{},\"pSeries\":{},\"playlist\":{\"item_num\":0},\"shouldReturn404\":false,\"item_id\":\"\",\"key\":undefined},\"CinemaChannelFeed\":[],\"CinemaFeedRebojiemu\":[],\"CinemaFeedFromRedis\":[],\"MyWatchHistory\":[{\"type\":\"all\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true},{\"type\":\"svideo\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true},{\"type\":\"lvideo\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true}],\"MyFavorite\":[{\"type\":\"all\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true},{\"type\":\"svideo\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true},{\"type\":\"lvideo\",\"videoFeed\":[],\"hasMore\":true}],\"AuthorDetailInfo\":{\"user_id\":\"58484635562\",\"media_id\":\"1562629337991170\",\"name\":\"鼎力推鉴王鼎杰工作室\",\"introduce\":\"小细节里的大战略，大格局里的小动作。\",\"avatar\":\"https:\\u002F\\u002Fsf3-cdn-tos.bdxiguastatic....
```

But whenever I try to print ["AuthorDetailInfo"] I got an error.

```python
print(script["AuthorDetailInfo"])
```

Error result

```
print(script["AuthorDetailInfo"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

How can i print this? And how can i remove all backslash from JSON?

Code

```python
print(script["AuthorDetailInfo"])
```

Expected result

```
{
 "user_id":"58484635562",
 "media_id":"1562629337991170",
 "name":"鼎力推鉴王鼎杰工作室",
 "introduce":"小细节里的大战略"...
}
```

Edit: I solved the problem by using `re` module.

Code

```
import requests, json, re, base64
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
head = {
    "Accept": 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,km;q=0.7",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Cookie": "",
    "Host": "www.ixigua.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
url = ""
ree = requests.get(url, headers=head).text

pattern = re.compile('(?<=window._SSR_HYDRATED_DATA=).*?(?=</script>)')
jsonResult = pattern.findall(ree)[0]
jsonResult = jsonResult.replace(':undefined', ':null')
jsonData = json.loads(jsonResult)

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(jsonData, f, ensure_ascii = False, indent=4)
```

Comment: Sadly, I have blank page opening the URL, but you can try `data = json.loads(re.search(r'window\._SSR_HYDRATED_DATA=(.*);', script).group(1))` and then `data` should be normal python dict.

Comment: You got a javascript script as text. There is no general way to extract information from it (even a js parser would only be able to get static content). But you may be able to hack it by splitting out just that first "=" and hope that the rest is JSON compatible.

Comment: You may be able to use selenium to load the page via a web browser in the hopes that the script puts this information in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`script` is JavaScript code, not JSON. Notice the `window._SSR_HYDRATED_DATA=` before the `{`. Everything after that can be treated as JSON (even though technically it isn't.) You have to deal with the variable assignment first. One way is to use `split()`:

```
_, my_json = script.split('=', maxsplit=1)
```

Now you can use `json.loads()` to parse it:

```
obj = my_json.loads(my_json)
```

And finally you can get the part you want:

```
print(obj['AuthorDetailInfo'])
```

Note: The `maxsplit=1` is just in case there are any other `=` characters in the string. Also, this only works if the JavaScript object in the assignment is valid JSON.

Comment: You could do `_, my_json = script.split('=', maxsplit=1)`. Of course, its still hoping that the only thing in that script is a json compatible object.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for the suggestion. That would deal with the possibility of multiple `=` characters.

Comment: I got an error
`obj = my_json.loads(my_json)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'loads'`

Comment: It works if I change it to `json.dumps(my_json)`. But it just remove the `'='` from the file.

Comment: @Heng Did you also remove the variable name? If so then that sounds great since it is probably now actually valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, then it will still get the same error `print(script["AuthorDetailInfo"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers` like before

Comment: I finally be able to solve this by using re module.  `pattern = re.compile('(?<=window._SSR_HYDRATED_DATA=).*?(?=</script>)')
    my_json = pattern.findall(response)[0] jsonResult = my_json.replace(':undefined', ':"undefined"')`

Comment: @Heng Alternatively you can replace `undefined` with `null`. This would give you a more accurate conversion because the string `"undefined"` is very different from the JavaScript value `undefined`. JavaScript's `undefined` is closer to the JSON value `null`. And `null` in JSON will translate to `None` in python when you use `loads()`.

Comment: @Heng Also, feel free to post an answer with properly formatted code. That way future visitors can see the solution you found. Maybe someone will find it helpful.